# MongoDB stage to C# API

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb

hope you are all fine.
I had my first contact with MongoDB the last weekend e and now I'm facing a problem.
I just would like to limit the data that is going to be shown in the front end..

I've got a C# API with Get action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<dynamic> Get(string country)
{
    if(country is null)
        return  _country.Find<dynamic>(new BsonDocument()).ToList();

    var filter= Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Eq("country", country);
    return _country.Find(filter).ToList();
}
```

and I also got a simple MongoDB stage

```
new BsonArray
{
    new BsonDocument("$limit", 5),
    new BsonDocument()
}
```

I've spent many hours trying to figure out hot to implement the MongoDB code to my API but I just can't imagine how.

Can anyone give a tip?

Answer (score 1):

You missed that a stage is a concept that is used in [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). In your example you're using a [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/) operation that has appropriate options [class](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptions_2_Limit.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved it.
The only thing I needed to get what i wanted was to code ".limit(number)".

The final code got like this

```
return  _employees.Find<dynamic>(new BsonDocument()).Limit(4).ToList();
```